# Whats wrong with my .desktop file?

Tags: unity, appmenu

I tried to create a basic application that I can run and stick to the launcher, and I wanted to create it with a .desktop file. I cant figure out whats wrong with this file. It says "There was an error launching the application".

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Games        
Comment=opens games dir
Exec=gnome-terminal -e "nautilus ~/Games"
Icon=utilities-terminal
Terminal=false 
Type=Application
Categories=Application;
```

Edit: Its solved now, I had to save the file as .desktop file from a text editor, doing cat > Games.desktop breaks something, even if it seems like it identifies correctly. The problem with ~ mentioned below was present as well.

Answer (score 0):

`.desktop` file are not shell scripts. `~` is a shortcut expanded by the shell. Replace `"nautilus ~/Games"` with `"nautilus /home/USER/Games"`

Comment: didnt work, sorry. Changed it to 'Exec=gnome-terminal -e "nautilus /home/USER/Games"'. Tried replacing USER with my username as well.

Comment: Did you replace `/home/USER/Games` with `/home/$USER/Games`?

Comment: Why is `gnome-terminal` needed here at all? `Exec=nautilus /home/username/Games` will do it, surely?

Answer (score 0):

The way you do it, change `Exec=gnome-terminal -e "nautilus ~/Games"` to `Exec=gnome-terminal -e "nautilus Games"`. Nautilus uses your home as a starting point, so ~/Games becomes /home/user/~/Games, which most likely doesn't exist. So for instance, if you wanted to open the /home directory, you could do `Exec=nautilus ../`, because that's relative to your home directory.

But if you have no other reason for using gnome-terminal, you should probably change it to `Exec=nautilus Games`.

Comment: the thing is that it doesnt work no matter what command I type to exec. Not only nautilus but any terminal command

Comment: Yes, the one I gave you does work. Keep in mind you need to run "update-desktop-database" in order for changes to used by the system. If not, then you might've stored your desktop file in the wrong location.